# Correct parameters for wngram2idngram?

Tags: sphinx4, pocketsphinx, language-model

I am trying to generate the arpa format language model with the following commands:

```
text2wngram < weather.txt | grep -v "</s> <s>" > weather.wngram
wngram2idngram -vocab weather.vocab < weather.wngram > weather.idngram 
idngram2lm -vocab_type 0 -idngram weather.idngram -vocab weather.vocab -arpa weather.lm
```

But second command ***wngram2idngram***  is not working and throwing following error:

***text2idngram : Error : Must specify idngram file.***

I change the parameters as follows and it works.

```
wngram2idngram -vocab weather.vocab -idngram weather.idngram < weather.wngram
```

My question is which one is correct?
I am using cmulmtk Version 3.

Answer (score 1):

Second variant is correct.

At the same time, we recommend to use SRILM.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I will try SRILM.